# How to create Silver light masterpage?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am new to silver light, i created one sample silver light application but i want to create mater page in silver light, in silver light master page exist? or not?, if exist please help me how to create that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a Silverlight project using the VS2010 Navigation project template you will see a file named MainPage.xaml.  This is the equivalent of a master page.

Comment: Hello Myles. I am adding frames to add another pages same as contentprovider in asp.net. But frame is not displaying the complete content . Please provide a proper solution. thanks in advance